# how to popup after ajax "success:"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have a button, when i clicks this button it will goes to  ajax. In the suceess condition,it returns three values for 'data' which are 1,2,3. i want to popup a login form only when data=1.(if the user is not logged in). pls help me.

```
 <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#xmpModal" class="btn green btn-success" onclick="get('<?echo $u_id;?>','<?echo $e_id;?>')">click</button>
```

**popup div**

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="exmpModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">Ã—</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h3 class="modal-title" id="lineModalLabel">My Modal</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <!-- content goes here -->
                        <form>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>

                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                  </form>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="group button">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"  role="button">Close</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-delete hidden" role="group">
                        <button type="button" id="delImage" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-red" data-dismiss="modal"  role="button">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button type="button" id="saveImage" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-green" data-action="save" role="button">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ajax**

```
  function get(u_id,e_id)
{
    $.ajax({

        url: "<?echo base_url()?>events/xyz",
        type: 'post',   // HTTP METHOD
        data: 
        {u_id:u_id,e_id:e_id  },


        success: function(data)
        {  

             //alert(data);  
            if(data==1) 
            {
                // add your code pls
            }                                    
           else if(data==2)

           {
                alert("hai");

           }
           else if(data==3)   
           {
             alert("hello"); 
           }        
        }

      });
  }
```

**my function in php controller**

```
    public function xyz()
{      
    $u_id=$this->input->post('u_id');
    $e_id=$this->input->post('e_id');        
    $temp=$this->session->userdata('user');
    $g=$this->xm->is_going($u_id,$e_id);
    $g1=$this->xm->is_going1($u_id,$e_id);
    if($temp=="")
    {          
       $d=1;
       echo $d;

    }
    else if($g==$u_id)
        {

           $d=2;
           echo $d;

        }
        else if($g1==$u_id)
            {

                $d=3;
                echo $d;
                $this->xm->event_updation($e_id,$u_id);
            }
            else
            {           
                $data=array('event_id'=>$e_id,'ev_going'=>$u_id);             
                $this->xm->eventgoing($data);          
     }
   }
```

Comment: You need to return in json from controller like this: return Response::json(array('data'=>'values'));

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're getting `1, 2, 3` properly and can manipulate them, so just need to do is to show `modal`

```
if($data == 2){
    $('#exmpModal').modal('show');
}
```

[you can read more about Modal here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods)

more [Specifically](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modalshow)

Answer (score 0):

> You need to return in json from controller like this:

I'm not sure what framework did u use but this example is laravel framework when returning json.

```
return Response::json(array('response'=>'values'));
```

> In your js success function:

```
success: function(data)
        { 
            if(data.response==1) 
            {
                // add your code pls
            }                                    
           else if(data.response==2)

           {
                alert("hai");

           }
           else if(data.response==3)   
           {
             alert("hello"); 
           }        
        }
```

Comment: no.... i have created my popup modal via data attributes. so in all three conditions the popup is showing.

Comment: Can you put your codes in jsfiddle? so that we can check the possible error

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, re-check value returned from `data` as your expectation, then you can refer to this post how to show a popup login dialog. Plz note that you have to write some code to check user login status before doing it.

[Create A Simple Login Form On Popup Box Using jQuery](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/create-a-login-form-on-popup-box-using-jquery.php)